# Invalid Pom project file when sending request to include bintray package in jcenter

Tags: maven, pom.xml, bintray, jcenter

First of all, I successfully linked multiple projects to JCenter before and am at a loss why I am not able to submit an inclusion request for this specific package.

The following error message pops up when trying to follow the "add to Jcenter" steps.

[image]

The package in question: https://bintray.com/kilianb/maven/pcg-java

*The pom:*

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <!-- Project settings -->
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.github.kilianB</groupId>
    <artifactId>pcg-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <javac.target>10</javac.target>
        <bintrayRepository>maven</bintrayRepository>
        <bintrayPackage>pcg-java</bintrayPackage>
    </properties>

    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>MIT</name>
            <url>https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT</url>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <developers>
        <developer>
            <name>Kilian Brachtendorf</name>
            <email>Kilian.Brachtendorf@t-online.de</email>
            <roles>
                <role>developer</role>
            </roles>
            <timezone>Europe/Berlin</timezone>
        </developer>
    </developers>

    <!-- JUnit 5 -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerVersion>10</compilerVersion>
                    <source>${javac.target}</source>
                    <target>${javac.target}</target>
                    <excludes>
                        <!-- -->
                        <exclude>**/doNotUse/**/*</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/statBenchmark/**/*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludePackageNames>com.github.kilianB.pcg.doNotUse:com.github.kilianB.statBenchmark</excludePackageNames>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <!-- Environment Settings -->
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>bintray-kilianb-maven</id>
            <name>kilianb-maven</name>
            <url>https://api.bintray.com/maven/kilianb/${bintrayRepository}//${bintrayPackage}/</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

</project>
```

Everything builds without errors and installed in my local maven repository the artifact can be used without any issues. How is this **pom** invalid or which mandatory information is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by manually adding the xml header as well as the scm tag to my pom file, which eclipse does not add by default. Strangely enough these pom files were accepted a while ago.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the same problem and couldn't find any documentation on what information jcenter requires. I added the following fields:

- name
- description
- licenses
- scm
- developers

With these fields in my pom I was able to send my inclusion request.

I don't know if all of them are required. I suppose at least name and description (which are both missing in your pom) are.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added both fields to the pom and still receive the same error. My other projects were included without those two asl well. When sending the include request we do check the box (is pom projects) don't be? I couldn't find anything in the guides or description about this checkbox.